# C# Lock on the objects inside a SynchronizedCollection

Tags: c#

Is it OK to lock on the objects inside a SynchronizedCollection ?

In the example below, the SynchronizedCollection contains others SynchronizedCollection.

```
private SynchronizedCollection<SynchronizedCollection<bool>> _lockCollection;

lock (_lockCollection[stationId])
{
     /* Synchronized code here */
}
```

Is this code OK?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **Yes**. You can lock on the SynchronizedCollection returned by your SynchronizedCollection ... (That statement by itself seems questionable)

The longer answer has a few considerations ...

1. Whether or not you should do this at all depends on your purpose and application. The collection itself locks on a shared "sync" object and thus would not conflict with the lock you are creating.
2. The collection itself performs internal locking so do you really need to lock on it? What operation are you performing inside your lock that would justify this?

Comment: Inside the lock I do `_nextIdDictionary[stationId] = id + 1;`  _nextIdDictionary being a ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: That doesn't make sense ... Your return value for _lockCollection[stationId] is SynchronizedCollection<bool>. What does your statement have to do with the SynchronizedCollection<bool> that is returned?

Comment: I should have just replied that inside the lock I am incrementing an int

Comment: Why are you locking on that collection? How does it correlate to your integer operation? The operation of id + 1 is going to be atomic and thread safe by default.

Comment: It would make sense to lock on the collection containing the integer, if you are worried about the value in that position changing before you read/write the incremented value.